# get the output of for loop and insert it into an arraylist in java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

How do i get the values of the output of my for loop and add them to my 
`arraylist`   so if the output of my loop is like
`string1`,`string2`, `string3`  how do i put this into my arraylist

```
List<String> tpc = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    topics[i] = topics[i].trim();
}
```

Comment: tpc.add(topics[i]);  Put if after your "topics[i] = topics[i].trim();"

Comment: btw you should declare tpc as ArrayList<String> instead of as a List<String>

Comment: @WilliamKu No. List<String> is better if he decides to change the implementation to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply use the add method that is included with the ArrayList class.

```
ArrayList<String> tpc = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    topics[i] = topics[i].trim();
    tpc.add(topics[i]);
}
```

Here is a example of how you can insert your value into your arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Use add method of arraylist as follows

```
tpc.add(topics[i])
```